# Why doesn't blender use my graphics card?

Tags: rendering

Before installing a graphics card, I was working on a very weak intel card. I tried to render a scene but the quality of the image was poor and it took 1 minute to render.

After buying and installing Nvidia GT 710, I tried to render the same scene and I was expecting to get better results but I got the same results.

It seems that blender doesn't use my new graphics card. How do I know which card does blender use? How to switch between them?

**Edit:**

I like the answer but I only have the CPU option. Version: 2.73a linux 64-bit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blender head to **File** -> **User Preferences** -> **System**.

At the bottom left under "**Cycles Computer Device**" choose "**CUDA**" and you should see your GPU underneath. You need to be using the Cycles render engine for this to take effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I wanna give it the best answer but I can't find this option. I put a screenshot in the question.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the latest version of Blender if you are able, which is 2.79b at the time of this post. You can do that here: https://www.blender.org/download/

You may also need to install the latest nVidia drivers to support CUDA functionality.